# Is a de-obfuscated version of the realtime api available?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm running into issues with the realtime API and I'm unable to track down the root cause due to the obfuscation of the realtime library.
All I can see in the console is something like this when loading the document:

```
TypeError: a.b is null
...,A(a.aa,a));var f=b.requestParams,g;for(g in f)f.hasOwnProperty(g)&&e.X(g,f[g]);...
api (line 211)
```

Any ideas how to resolve such an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a de-obfuscated version available.  If you post the specifics of what you are trying to accomplish, and the full stack of when you get an error, someone may be able to help.

Comment: Any plans to make one available, or is it a matter of policy?